# Marketing Cloud - Schedule vs Export

Tags: marketing-cloud

I need to be able to give users access to schedule but not to export from Marketing Cloud reports tab. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The export and schedule settings to Allow/Deny for a user is set together in Marketing Cloud. You can either give both permissions or deny both permissions but not independently!

[image]